# In Drupal 7, Where is field settings data stored? (Not the field data)

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to update my field's data tables structure manually via phpmyadmin as I cannot modify it via the fields settings page since i have data in them. The thing is, where do I update the "fields settings" to encompass these table structure changes?

Comment: In field_config. I would never recommend doing this - can you elaborate on why?

Comment: i need to update a a Date field to encompass "recurring" dates. Since i have data in that field already, the UI does not let me change that field setting.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Base field data is in `field_config`, and instance data is in `field_config_instance`. Rather than modifying them manually, though, you can always use the API:

```
$field = field_info_field('field_name');
$field['key'] = $new_value;
field_update_field($field);
```

Or for an instance

```
$instance = field_info_instance('node', 'field_name', 'article');
$instance['key'] = $new_value;
field_update_instance($instance);
```

Using the API will clear the appropriate caches, and it's just a better idea than editing the data manually.

Either way, make sure to backup the database first in case something goes horribly wrong :)

Comment: Direct SQL alteration also means that `hook_field_update_field()` doesn't fire.  That may or may not cause problems.

Comment: Oh, and a module can forbid alteration even if you use the API, and having data is a potential case for denial.

Comment: whats the difference from field_config and field_config_instance tables?

Comment: also if i used the API's how would i know what they KEY that corresponds to the field setting i want to change? Here's a snapshot of what I found for the field_config table: http://img818.imageshack.us/img818/8804/e1yu.png ... it seems that the field settings is stored in the DATA column which cannot modify since its binary data?

Comment: field_config has the base field data (field name, type, cardinality, etc) and field_config_instance has the per-bundle settings (e.g. the specific settings for a field attached to a certain content type). The data column contains a serialised php string, which is why it's not recommended to edit the data directly. Using the info functions you can get the field/instance data, use `dpm()` or similar to inspect it, change some values just like you would a normal array, then use the update function to persist the changes

Comment: do you have an example of how this can be done? thanks clive!

Comment: Can a new field value be added?